# Getting error when using Xamarin sharpie tool with BarcodeScanner cocoapod

Tags: ios, swift, xamarin, cocoapods

When I run the following sharpie command:

> sharpie pod init ios BarcodeScanner

I get this error:

> Installing BarcodeScanner (4.1.3) [!] Unable to determine Swift
> version for the following pods:
>
> `BarcodeScanner` does not specify a Swift version and none of the targets (`ObjectiveSharpieIntegration`) integrating it have the
> `SWIFT_VERSION` attribute set. Please contact the author or set the
> `SWIFT_VERSION` attribute in at least one of the targets that
> integrate this pod.
>
> error: could not install CocoaPod

If I try to init with other cocoapods, like AFNetworking from the sharpie docs, it works and I can then run the bind command.  Any idea how to get around this error with BarcodeScanner?

Comment: Swift-based frameworks are not directly supported by the sharpie tool (nor the `Xamarin.iOS` build tools). You can use the `bind` option and directly pass additional clang options (`-clang`). Also you will need to include the correct Swift frameworks into your project (there are a bunch of 3rd-party packages available via Nuget and Github for the various Swift versions)

Comment: Bummer.  Would be nice if all these cocoa libraries were easily accessible.  It looks like the sharpie utility has not been updated in a while so this support may not come anytime soon unfortunately.  I'll look for a different route.  Thanks.